# How to query the `pip` command, to get the FQDM it will use?

Tags: pip

Is there a way to query the `pip` command (or another way), to get the FQDN of the server `pip` will use (e.g., in `pip install`)?

Comment: bw more specific with your question, whats the goal? hostname -f shows the full fqdn of the server

Comment: @djdomi: I need to exclude all `pip` servers from deep-inspection by my FortiGate firewall. Thus, I need to inform the firewall of the FQDN of the pip server. (https://www.google.com/search?q=deep-inspection+by+my+FortiGate&oq=deep-inspection+by+my+FortiGate&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: hm, pleqse expand your post, its missing from which os you want the information, or from what kind device

Comment: After some more research, @djdomi, seems that all I can do is add `pypi.python.org` to my FortiGate firewall security policy, and then when PyPI redirects to an external pip server, I'd fail on that new pip server, and would have to add that new pip server to my FortiGate firewall configuration. Seems there's no way to know in advance which pip servers would be used.

Comment: nslookup or dig pypi. python. org or look on the page. i. e. for Debian you could either use de. debian. org which round Robin it or select a direct mirror - maybe its also possible to pip?